# Lista de números aleatórios sem repetição Android

Tags: android, lista, random, arraylist

Eu tenho um ArrayList com N itens dentro e eu preciso agrupa-los aleatoriamente em 2 conjuntos de X itens e o restante em um outro conjunto. Porém, nenhum deles podem se repetir.

Por exemplo: meu ArrayList tem 20 itens adicionados e eu quero dividi-lo em 2 grupos de 7 e, os 6 restantes, em um outro conjunto. Só que, a escolha desses itens para compor os conjuntos tem que ser aleatória (random) e nenhum desses 20 pode se repetir em nenhum dos conjuntos.

Eu tenho conhecimento da classe Random e estou utilizando-a, mas o problema está sendo na hora de comparar os novos números gerados com os anteriores, para que não haja repetidos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma abordagem possível é ordenar aleatoriamente(embaralhar) o ArrayList de 20 itens e extrair dele os outros.

Exemplo para um ArrayList de 20 inteiros:

```
ArrayList<Integer> original = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i< 20; i++){
    original.add(i);
}

//Clone o original caso o queira manter inalterado
ArrayList<Integer> embaralhado = (ArrayList<Integer>) original.clone();

//Embaralha
Collections.shuffle(embaralhado);

ArrayList<Integer> grupo1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> grupo2 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> grupo3 = new ArrayList<>();

//Percorre o ArrayList embaralhado e distribui os seus itens pelos grupos.
for(int i=0; i < embaralhado.size(); i++){
   if(i < 7)grupo1.add(embaralhado.get(i));
   else if(i < 14)grupo2.add(embaralhado.get(i));
   else grupo3.add(embaralhado.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Eduardo, era isto que procurava? Ela resolve o seu problema?

Comment: Muito obrigado por sua resposta, Ramaral. Eu fiz algo parecido com o seu (extrair de um Array principal e dividir na quantidade de conjuntos desejado). Só que fiz isso usando o Random mesmo, porém a sua versão está muito mais enxuta e limpa. Obrigado novamente e parabéns!

Comment: Ainda bem que pude ajudar e bem vindo ao StackOverflow. Veja [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) a forma de proceder quando uma resposta te foi útil.